# How to change labels in SourceForge bug tracker?

Tags: sourceforge

I am working on a project (Maxima) hosted at SourceForge. I am thinking about changing some labels. For example, if a label is now `Foo Bar` I might want it to be just `Bar`.

Is there a way to change the text for a label?

I suppose I could find all the items labelled `Foo Bar`, label them with `Bar`, then delete the `Foo Bar` label.

That seems error prone and tedious. Is there a better way?

I looked for a user forum at SourceForge itself, but didn't find one.

Comment: You could ask on IRC (#sourceforge on freenode.net): http://webchat.freenode.net/?randomnick=0&channels=sourceforge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking on #sourceforge (thanks to @chirlu for the hint) it appears the only way to do it automatically is to use the [Allura API](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Allura%20API/#tracker).